# During a dimensional analysis, why is it not allowed to take the absolute value?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

If I know that a formula depends only on two quantities $l$ and $t$ which are in "independent" units (say length and time), why can I only look for an expression of the form $Cm^\alpha t^\beta$ thus excluding for example $|l|\cdot t$?

Comment: Who forbids you from doing so?

Comment: Dimensional analysis is not concerned with values.

Comment: *Dimensional analysis* is about comparing the units of left and right side of an equation and trying to establish a relationship from that. For example if you are given that the *time period* of a pendulum depends on the *length*, *acceleration due to gravity*, we try find how it's related if the *time period* is proportional to the square or cube or square root of the *length*, *acceleration due to gravity*. Like finding the power relation.

Comment: This question simply does not make sense. The only way to answer is to re-explain what dimensional analysis is, and why the question does not make sense. In that light, it should be closed as overly broad. Or, more directly, it should be closed as unclear.

Comment: If it does not make sense to you, that does mean it should be closed. I'm not asking about what DA is but about why a particular operation is not usually considered as valid when doing it

Answer (score 3):

Dimensional analysis doesn't have the limitation you suggest. It allows you to add any quantities, hereafter *terms*, of the same dimension. These terms are products of what we'll call *factors* . These factors may be a length $l$, a power thereof e.g. $l^a$, or even e.g. $l^b|l|^c$. It doesn't really matter, because that last example is just $\pm l^{b+c}$; that $\pm$ sign, while $l$-dependent, won't change the units.

Ultimately, in dimensional analysis we only care about what the terms are *up to dimensionless coefficients* , if only because that's all we can determine. If $v$ is the speed of a Newtonian particle of mass $m$, dimensional analysis can tell you the kinetic energy is "something like" $mv^2$, but that could be $\frac{\sqrt[5]{3}}{18\pi^e}mv|v|(9-\tfrac{v}{|v|})$ for all we know. Of course, there are other arguments you can make to exclude ideas like that (perhaps discussing continuity or differentiability), not to mention derivations of the unique result $\frac12mv^2$.

So, dimensional analysis might tell you a particular quantity is something like $mv^2$ plus something like $mgh$ plus something like $q^2/(\epsilon_0r)$ etc. Its job is to work out (up to dimensionless coefficients) which kinds of terms are legal in a given context.

Comment: Isn't the dimensionless factor supposed to be constant (i.e. independent from the quantities)? If you write $|l|=l\cdot{\rm sign}(l)$ (or $\pm$ as in your question), then the leading factor is not constant

Comment: And thanks for your answer

Comment: @Laravel You can't refute dimensionless but variable factors with dimensional analysis. Indeed, they sometimes exist, e.g. $\frac{\omega^3}{e^{\beta\hbar\omega}-1}$.